# Getting error "A JobRepository has not been set" when trying to autowire a jobLauncher

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I'm currently trying to run a Spring Batch process by autowiring the jobLauncher into the controller, exactly what the asker of the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114162/spring-batch-starting-a-job-from-within-a-spring-mvc-contorller-with-a-new-thre) is trying to do. However, I'm getting an error telling me that my autowire failed and that a "`JobRepository has not been set`", which is caused by the [`afterPropertiesSet()` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/2.1.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/SimpleJobLauncher.java#SimpleJobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet%28%29) on the `SimpleJobLauncher`. Would anyone know what might be causing this?

Here's the Spring configuration from the other asker, which I'm also using:

```
   <job id="writeProductsJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="readWrite">
            <tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor">
                <chunk reader="productItemReader" writer="productItemWriter" commit-interval="10" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>
    
    <bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
```

**Edit**: Here's the configuration for `tranactionManager`, `jobRepository`, and `jobLauncher`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

  <bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jobLauncher" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you add the configuration for your SimpleJobLauncher?

Comment: @MichaelMinella I just added the configuration to my question.

Comment: Your configurations above now have two jobRepository bean definitions (one with a taskExecutor and one without).  Which are you using or do your really have two defined?

Comment: @MichaelMinella I really have two defined. I guess that breaks it?

Comment: Having two beans defined within the same context with the same id will break.  I'm actually surprised you aren't getting other errors to that effect before the issue you're having.  If you rename one, that should at least help.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I had this problem and I find a way with Spring Batch 5.0.2. You can solve the problem adding H2 database dependency

```
implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
```

in Gradle or

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in Maven. And then set it in job

```java
jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
return jobLauncher;
```

---

The H2 database dependency is not necessary if you have another data source like PostgreSQL database or MondoDB or whatever, but any data source is necessary because otherwise it's missing in the job repository and it cannot be created – my guess it's something with transaction manager.

*Note*: The problem happened to me without `afterPropertiesSet()` and I'm using `TaskExecutorJobLauncher` as `SimpleJobLauncher` was deprecated in version 5.0.0.