# Issues triggering a batch job from Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am trying to trigger a batch job through a web url (Servlet/Spring MVC) which is working perfectly when initiated from a main program. When I start the web server and hit the url the program gives me an exception that jobLauncher is not resolved.

This is the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114162/spring-batch-starting-a-job-from-within-a-spring-mvc-contorller-with-a-new-thre) which is pretty close to my requirement, but I want to see if my current approach be corrected before moving to the suggestion there which is also a multi-threaded (not really required for me at this point)

Here's my perfectly working [configuration](https://gist.github.com/gistoneworld/cfde0df6f26063380bfd), [batch-config](https://gist.github.com/gistoneworld/ffb4a37b12a3da6a099e), [Main program](https://gist.github.com/gistoneworld/582d59d51d35dacb2911). I am invoking my spring batch through the [servlet here](https://gist.github.com/gistoneworld/07255a0ff62724835f23)

> 11:02:37.201 [tomcat-http--24] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
>   - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction 11:02:37.202 [tomcat-http--24] INFO
>   o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob:
>   [name=db2FileJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{a=aa,
>   b=123, c=ccc, d=11,22,33}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
>   11:02:37.204 [tomcat-http--24] DEBUG
>   o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet()
>   on bean with name 'jobLauncher' 11:02:37.205 [tomcat-http--24] DEBUG
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name
>   'jobLauncher' in servlet with name 'mint-gateway' at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>   [servlet-api.jar:na] at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   [servlet-api.jar:na] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:177)
>   [spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>   [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>   [spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>   [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>   [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>   [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>   [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>   [spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.50.C] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [na:1.7.0_51] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [na:1.7.0_51] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
>   11:02:37.205 [tomcat-http--24] DEBUG
>   o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - Closing JPA EntityManager in
>   OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter 11:02:37.205 [tomcat-http--24] DEBUG
>   o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
>   11:02:37.205 [tomcat-http--24] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is
>   empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in
>   HttpSession. 11:02:37.205 [tomcat-http--24] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now
>   cleared, as request processing completed Jul 21, 2014 11:02:37 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [mint-gateway] in context with path
>   [/mintgw] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name
>   'jobLauncher' in servlet with name 'mint-gateway'] with root cause
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name
>   'jobLauncher' in servlet with name 'mint-gateway' at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:177)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>
> 11:02:37.206 [tomcat-http--24] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>   - DispatcherServlet with name 'mint-gateway' processing GET request for [/mintgw/uncaughtException] 11:02:37.207 [tomcat-http--24] DEBUG
>   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method
>   for path /uncaughtException

Deeply appreciate any help here, I am newbie to Spring world. Thanks.

**Update 2**

Changing the program as per the suggestion in the [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114162/spring-batch-starting-a-job-from-within-a-spring-mvc-contorller-with-a-new-thre?answertab=active#tab-top); ie., `<batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor">` with Task gets me the exception [here in Gist](https://gist.github.com/gistoneworld/8c57cb0da5bc48b713ac) due to space limits on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The exception seems to be because the view no longer exists since you are running your job on your current view session.

I suggest run a job in the background, add the batch request on the database, and let your batch job poll that database w/o letting the view trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Spring-batch-admin module? I think your requirement can be fulfilled by spring-batch-admin. this application consists of a web UI using Spring MVC, a Java service API and a RESTful (JSON) API for managing and monitoring Spring Batch jobs.